# protobuf : Optional attributes' values are not cleared

Tags: python, json, protocol-buffers, proto

we are currently running a python application that receives json messages, parse it according to the given dict using `ParseDict` , serialize it `SerializeToString` and send it.

```
# encode.py
from google.protobuf.json_format import ParseDict



payload = ParseDict(data, data_t_v1())
raw_payload = payload.SerializeToString()
```

This what we have in proto file:

```
//data.proto syntax = "proto2";

message data_t_v1 {
 required uint32 id = 1;
 optional uint32 offset = 2;
 optional uint32 multiplier = 3;
 optional uint32 mask = 4;
 }
```

However, when I was testing different scenarios, I had an issue concerning the values of optional attributes. Here is what happens:

Test 1- sending the message with the optional values

```
data = {
"id": 1,
"offset": 2,
"multiplier":10,
"mask": 4294967295 }
```

Test 2- sending the same message without the optional values

```
data = {
"id": 1 }
```

The issue happens here: `ParseDict` is returning a dict with the optional attributes having the old values that I set in Test 1.

I would like to know if there is a way to clear old optional values when they are not set.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you create a new instance of your proto message for each test?

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import ParseDict

# Create a new msg
msg = your_packge_pb2.data_t_v1()

data = {
  "id": 1,
  "offset": 2,
  "multiplier":10,
  "mask": 4294967295,
}

# Parse data into msg
ParseDict(data, msg)

# Do something with msg
print(msg)

# Create a new msg
msg = your_packge_pb2.data_t_v1()

data = {
  "id": 1,
}

# Parse data into msg
ParseDict(data, msg)

# Do something with msg
print(msg)
```

> **NOTE** The [style guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style#message_and_field_names) recommends using `PascalCase` for message names rather than `snake_case`.

Comment: This was the issue:
all my proto messages instances were created once in the init in a Dict. and I was using 
 the same instance when I call parseDict.

As u suggested, creating the instance every time before parsing is solving the issue.
thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!